# Which features of C# 7.0 are available in VS "15" Preview?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

As you know in build 2016 conference, next version of visual studio was introduced as **Visual Studio Enterprise “15” Preview**. I downloaded ISO of this preview to check out C# 7.0 new features. As was said in C# presentation session on build conference, I added `__DEMO__` and `__DEMO_EXPERIMENTAL__` conditional compilation symbols to my project. Now I got these features working:

- Local Functions
- Digit Separators
- Binary Literals
- Pattern Matching

But these two do not working and build fails with errors:

- Ref Returns and Ref Locals
- Tuple Literal Syntax

Can you help me why I can not test these two last feature?

Comment: @jesse Instead of manually retagging all the questions that had a [tag:visual-studio-15] tag, you should have created (or asked a moderator to) a synonym, linking [visual-studio-15] to the master tag [visual-studio-2017]. It's a lot less work, doesn't bump up all of the questions, and ensures perpetual correctness any time someone tries to use the actual version number.

Answer (score 5):

As of today, *April 12, 2016 @ 12:16 PM (CDT)* the `tuple` feature is in its "prototyping" phase and not yet available. This is regardless of the conditional compilation symbols. Please check out the [**Roslyn** language feature status for details on C# 7.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e56cb6f8223a1cbd9602a671fb665512253570c3/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md#c-70-and-vb-15).

Actually, in looking more closely at the list -- it seems as though `pattern matching` is in "prototyping" too, which means I must stand corrected. If that is the case, then you should be able to pull down the **Roslyn** compiler locally from the [`tuple` branch found here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/features/tuples). Then use this build to compile your experimental code as defined [here](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/lrn-quick-tip-how-to-test-out-c-7-features-with-roslyn/).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 15 Preview will only let you play with some of the proposed features of C# 7.0, more specifically:

- local functions
- digit separators
- binary literals
- ref returns
- and pattern matching

Basically the stuff you already mentioned. Here is the [source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/04/02/whats-new-for-c-and-vb-in-visual-studio/). It's unclear when the others will be made available.